# How did Josie convert?

Tags: plot-explanation, annihilation

In [Annihilation (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2798920/), there is a scene after the final bear attack where Lena and Josie are talking while sitting outside the house. If you look at Josie's arms, it looks like she is growing plants from them.

She informs Lena that she doesn't want to be part of Lena's nor Ventress' plan and then starts walking away into the trees. As this is happening, you can see Josie is turning into a plant.

Was it just happening already and she conceded or did she will it in some way? It seemed as if she made it happen by making a conscious choice.

Comment: She didn't. Lena didn't found her, just some other transformed.

Comment: @Mithoron What do you mean? Lena didn't "find her" because she had already transformed. You could clearly see her transforming as she was running away from Lena.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at Josie's dialogue in that scene:

> Imagine dying frightened and in pain, and having that as the only part of you which survives.
>   I wouldn't like that at all. **Ventress wants to face it.
>   You want to fight it.
>   But I don't think I want either of those things.**

her becoming part of Area X seems more like a passive lack of resistance, letting nature take its course, rather than an active will to join.

In the book the film is based on, there are frequent references to the biologist actively fighting the growing sensation inside her (the 'brightness'), strongly hinted to be her 'becoming' part of Area X, so this interpretation makes sense from the book's perspective:

> The    brightness  infecting   my  senses  had spread  to  my  chest;  I   can describe    it  no  other   way.    Internally, there   was a   brightness  in  me, a   kind    of prickling    energy  and anticipation    that    pushed  hard    against my  lack    of  sleep.  Was this    part    of  the change? But even    so, it  didn’t  matter—I    had no  way to  combat what might   be  happening   to  me.
>
> ...
>
> To keep    the brightness  in  check,  I would have    to  continue    to  become  wounded,    to  be  injured.    To  shock   my  system.
>
> ...
>
> When   I   finally picked  up  my  husband’s   journal and started to  read,   the brightness  washed  over    me  in  unending    waves   and connected   me  to  the earth, the  water,  the trees,  the air,    as  I   opened  up  and kept    on  opening.